# How to retry connections with wget?

Tags: linux, wget

I have a very unstable internet connection, and sometimes have to download files as large as 200 MB.

The problem is that the speed frequently drops and sits at `--, -K/s` and the process remains alive. I thought just to send some KILL signals to the process, but as I read [in the wget manual about signals](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Signals.html) it doesn't help.

How can I force `wget` to reinitialize itself and pick the download up where it left off after the connection drops and comes back up again?

I would like to leave `wget` running, and when I come back, I want to see it downloading, and not waiting with speed `--,-K/s`.

Answer (score 80):

In order to avoid the `--, -K/s` situations you can use `--read-timeout=seconds`. This will timeout the connection after the amount of seconds.

If you need to go beyond that you can use this setup

```
wget --retry-connrefused --waitretry=1 --read-timeout=20 --timeout=15 -t 0
```

This will retry refused connections and similar **fatal** errors (`--retry-connrefused`), it will wait 1 second before next retry (`--waitretry`), it will wait a maximum of 20 seconds in case no data is received and then try again (`--read-timeout`), it will wait max 15 seconds before the initial connection times out (`--timeout`) and finally it will retry an infinite number of times (`-t 0`).

You might also want to put this in a `while` loop in order to avoid local network failure and similar. In this case you also need to add `--continue` in order to continue the download where you left off. The following works well in Bash

```
while [ 1 ]; do
    wget --retry-connrefused --waitretry=1 --read-timeout=20 --timeout=15 -t 0 --continue
    if [ $? = 0 ]; then break; fi; # check return value, break if successful (0)
    sleep 1s;
done;
```

As a bonus tip you can also use `--no-dns-cache` in case the host balances your request between multiple servers by DNS.

Disclaimer: I do not recommend using this since it will spam the host in case the connection is unstable and it's kind of unwise to leave it unmonitored. However this is what you want in case you really need to download something and your connection doesn't work adequately.

Comment: by default `--read-timeout=900`. You could just wait 15 minutes and wget will  restart downloading.

Comment: Thanks for this "retry" help, but for me it still doesn't work 100%, because wget ends with:
Unable to establish SSL connection.
It doesn't retries on that error.
For reproducing try to wget https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins.io.key

Comment: There is also a `--retry-on-http-error=code` option. In my case the server returned errors 500 every now and then, so I needed to add the `--retry-on-http-error=500` to make it work.

Answer (score 35):

`--tries=number`

This option set number of retries to number. Specify 0 or ‘inf’ for infinite retrying.

`wget --tries=0 http://example.com/myfile.zip` should do it.

The default is to retry 20 times, with the **exception** of fatal errors like “connection refused” or “not found” (404), which are not retried.

Answer (score 3):

Would this help? On askubuntu.com, I found a question very similar to the one you are asking. Here is the link to it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/72663/how-to-make-wget-retry-download-if-speed-goes-below-certain-threshold

Comment: Link-only answers should be avoided